# php typecast constructor

Tags: php, oop, constructor, clone

I would like to typecast PHP exceptions. Consider the following code:

```
class myException extends Exception {
  function __construct( $mOrigin = "", $iCode = 0, Exception $oPrevious = null){
    if(is_string($mOrigin)){
      parent::__construct($mOrigin, $iCode, $oPrevious);
    } elseif ($mOrigin instanceof Exception) {
      parent::__construct($mOrigin->getMessage(),$mOrigin->getCode(),$mOrigin->getPrevious());
      $this->file = $mOrigin->getFile();
      $this->line = $mOrigin->getLine();
    } else {
      parent::__construct("\$mOrigin has wrong type", self::eFatal, $oPrevious);
    }
  }
```

The idea is to turn a standard Exception into a myException preserving the **original** stack trace. Since the variables holding the trace are private I cannot copy these values immediately and the CTOR produces a new one for myException.

The first idea was of course to use clone, but I can hardly re-assign $this, can I?

So what I'm trying to do is a C++ style typecast CTOR. Is there a sensible paradigm in PHP to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just set trace & previous the same way as file & line?

```
class myException extends Exception {
  function __construct( $mOrigin = "", $iCode = 0, Exception $oPrevious = null){
    if(is_string($mOrigin)){
      parent::__construct($mOrigin, $iCode, $oPrevious);
    } elseif ($mOrigin instanceof Exception) {
      parent::__construct($mOrigin->getMessage(),$mOrigin->getCode(),$mOrigin->getPrevious());
      $this->file     = $mOrigin->getFile();
      $this->line     = $mOrigin->getLine();
      $this->trace    = $mOrigin->getTrace();
      $this->previous = $mOrigin->getPrevious();
    } else {
      parent::__construct("\$mOrigin has wrong type", self::eFatal, $oPrevious);
    }
  }
```

EDIT:

See comments below regarding why I got away w/ this code earlier.

Why not turn your myException class into a decorator:

```
class myException extends Exception {
  private $_oException;

  function __construct( $mOrigin = "", $iCode = 0, Exception $oPrevious = null){
    if(is_string($mOrigin)){
      parent::__construct($mOrigin, $iCode, $oPrevious);
    } elseif ($mOrigin instanceof Exception) {
      $this->_oException = $mOrigin;
      parent::__construct($mOrigin->getMessage(),$mOrigin->getCode(),$mOrigin->getPrevious());
      $this->file     = $mOrigin->getFile();
      $this->line     = $mOrigin->getLine();
    } else {
      parent::__construct("\$mOrigin has wrong type", self::eFatal, $oPrevious);
    }
  }

  function getTrace()
  {
     return $this->_oException->getTrace();
  }

  function getPrevious()
  {
    return $this->_oException->getPrevious();
  }
}
```

FUTHER INFO:

I've followed up on php-general and it turns out this *is* the intended behavior and it works the same in Java et al as well.  You can override the member variable in child classes and have a separate store with the same name.  This compiles just fine in java

```
public class PrivateAccess
{
    private Boolean isAccessible = true;

    public Boolean getAccessible()
    {
        return isAccessible;
    }
}
class PrivateAccessChild extends PrivateAccess
{
    private Boolean isAccessible = false;

    public Boolean getAccessible()
    {
        return isAccessible;
    }

    public Boolean getParentAccessible()
    {
        return super.getAccessible();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        PrivateAccessChild pAccess = new PrivateAccessChild();

        if(!pAccess.getAccessible())
            System.out.println("we're hitting the child here...");

        if(pAccess.getParentAccessible())
            System.out.println("we're hitting the parent here...");

        System.out.println("we're done here...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `trace` and `previous` are **private** to `Exception`.

Comment: fair enough - strangely the code above runs w/o error or notice even w/ `error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT`, see if it works for you.

Comment: good lord, it looks like PHP simply doesn't complain when you try to set a private values the way it does when you call a private method from a subclass..., I have another idea; I'll post in a min.

Comment: LOL, after further experimentation it's clear you could even use PHP's goofy treatment of private member variables as a feature.  The original code will work if you add simple getter methods for getTrace & getPrevious in myException.

Comment: Cool, I guess I'll go with the decorator. This should keep working, even if they should fix the language some day. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Turns out that's expected behavior, check the addendum for more info.  I probly knew this when I was a freshmen in college, but just haven't ever had the need to override a member variable name in a subclass that I can recall since I've been developing PHP, but turns out that's the way it is.